# Datatables's sorting resets my date range search

Tags: jquery, datatable

So i have a date column in my datatables which have a custom filter built using date range instead of date picker.

```
$('#idOfTheDateRangePicker').on('apply.daterangepicker',                 
    function(ev, picker) {

        var start_date = picker.startDate.format('DD.MM.YYYY');
        var end_date = picker.endDate.format('DD.MM.YYYY');

        var position = $(this).attr('position');

        var min_date = createDate(start_date);
        var max_date = createDate(end_date);

        var filter = function(settings, data, index) {
            var data_date = createDate(data[position]);

            if(data_date >= min_date && data_date <= max_date) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        };

        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(filter);
        var table = $('#thisTableId').DataTable();
        table.draw();


    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.splice($.fn.dataTable.ext.search.indexOf(filter, 1));

});
```

This filter works fine for returning rows with date that is within the given date range.

Problem is, when i click the sorting function on the column header, it will resets the date range filter and show back all the rows. The sorting however doesnt break all of my non-range custom filters, like filter using select or datepicker, that passes single value to the table column search.

How can i make it so that the date range filter above stays applied to the table even when clicking the sorting button?

Comment: can you create example in fiddle?

Comment: @BhumiShah tried to emulate it in here - http://jsfiddle.net/bbLjzspf/3885/ but it didnt work, as in it didnt filter the table for me.

Comment: you have not added createDate function in that

Comment: Ouch. Thanks @BhumiShah .. heres the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bbLjzspf/3892/  Still didnt work..

Comment: Check now!! There was an issue in date function too!! added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thecreativedev/7895nv2b/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();

    var dataSet = [
        ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2018/04/25", "$320,800"],
        ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2018/07/25", "$170,750"],
        ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2018/01/12", "$86,000"],
        ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2018/03/29", "$433,060"],
        ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2018/11/28", "$162,700"],
        ["Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2018/12/02", "$372,000"],
        ["Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2018/08/06", "$137,500"],
        ["Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2018/10/14", "$327,900"],
        ["Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2018/09/15", "$205,500"],
        ["Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2018/12/13", "$103,600"],
        ["Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2018/12/19", "$90,560"],
        ["Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2018/03/03", "$342,000"],
        ["Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2018/10/16", "$470,600"],
        ["Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2018/12/18", "$313,500"],
        ["Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2018/03/17", "$385,750"],
        ["Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2018/11/27", "$198,500"],
        ["Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2018/06/09", "$725,000"],
        ["Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2018/04/10", "$237,500"],
        ["Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2018/10/13", "$132,000"],
        ["Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2018/09/26", "$217,500"],
        ["Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2018/09/03", "$345,000"],
        ["Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2018/06/25", "$675,000"],
        ["Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2018/12/12", "$106,450"],
        ["Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sidney", "3023", "2018/09/20", "$85,600"],
        ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2018/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
        ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2018/12/22", "$92,575"],
        ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2018/11/14", "$357,650"],
        ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2018/06/07", "$206,850"],
        ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2018/03/11", "$850,000"],
        ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2018/08/14", "$163,000"],
        ["Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sidney", "2769", "2018/06/02", "$95,400"],
        ["Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2018/10/22", "$114,500"],
        ["Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2018/05/07", "$145,000"],
        ["Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2018/10/26", "$235,500"],
        ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2018/03/09", "$324,050"],
        ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2018/12/09", "$85,675"]
    ];

    var columnDefs = [{
        title: "Name"
    }, {
        title: "Position"
    }, {
        title: "Office"
    }, {
        title: "Extn."
    }, {
        title: "Start date"
    }, {
        title: "Salary"
    }];

    var myTable;

    myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        data: dataSet,
        columns: columnDefs,
        dom: 'Bfrtip', // Needs button container
        select: 'single',
        responsive: true,
        altEditor: true, // Enable altEditor
        buttons: [{
                text: 'Add',
                name: 'add' // do not change name
            },
            {
                extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
                text: 'Edit',
                name: 'edit' // do not change name
            },
            {
                extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
                text: 'Delete',
                name: 'delete' // do not change name
            }
        ]
    });

    $('input[name="daterange"]').on('apply.daterangepicker',
        function(ev, picker) {

            var start_date = picker.startDate.format('YYYY.MM.DD');
            var end_date = picker.endDate.format('YYYY.MM.DD');

            var position = 4;

            var min_date = createDate(start_date);
            var max_date = createDate(end_date);
            var filter = function(settings, data, index) {
                var data_date = createDate(data[position]);

                if (data_date >= min_date && data_date <= max_date) {
                    console.log('if')
                    return true;
                } else {
                    console.log('else')
                    return false;
                }

            };
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(filter);
            myTable.draw();

        });
});

function createDate(dateString) {
    var year = dateString.substring(0, 4);
    var month = dateString.substring(5, 7);
    var day = dateString.substring(8, 10);
    return new Date(year, month, day).getTime();
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer above, i figured out why sorting would show back all the rows on the table. Thanks!